# Finding the area of $\triangle ABC$, if $a = \sqrt{6}$, $b+c = 3 + \sqrt{3}$, and $\angle A = \pi/3$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, $a = \sqrt{6}$, $b+c = 3 + \sqrt{3}$, and $\angle A = \pi/3$.
>
> Find the area of $\triangle ABC$.

I can't find the product of $bc$ so I can use the formula $A = \frac{bcsinA}{2}$.

I thought also at the Heron formula, but $p-b$ and $p-c$ gives me headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, in fact, can find the product $bc$ through one application of the cosine formula:
$$\cos A=\frac {b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
Also, $b^2+c^2=(b+c)^2-2bc$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.